# jQuery Storage and retrieval form state (with data)

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to store form state in for example cookie and retrieval it ?
I checked [serialize API](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) but I have no idea how to retrieval serialized data on the form.
Is it possible?

### Update

I putted my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BwUM4/1/). Check the javascript code after // End of cookie plugin becasue I am sure that jQuery plugin works right.

Comment: there is a plugin called [dumbFormState](http://www.jasonsebring.com/dumbFormState). try it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can serialize form values with `serialize()`.
Syntax:

```
$("#your_form").serialize()
```

will return a string you can handle, or save to cookie (you can use the jquery cookie plugin).

**EDIT**:
    The above code will serialize, but will be hard to retrieve.
You should better use `serializeArray()`, which returns an array of name value pairs ( like: `[{name: "age", value: "23"}, {name: "sex", value: "male"}]`). You can see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) for better explanation.

With that, we can build a "form to string" function and a "string back to form" function:

```
function form2string($form) {
  return JSON.stringify($form.serializeArray());
}

function string2form($form, serializedStr) {
  var fields = JSON.parse(serializedStr);
  for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
    var controlName = fields[i].name;
    var controlValue = fields[i].value;
    $form.find('[name=' + controlName + ']').val(controlValue);
  }
}
```

Use form2string to serialize it and string2form to set the string back to the form. To store and retrive the serialization, you can use the [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie).

Hope this helps. Cheers

PS: JSON methods will work only in modern browsers

Comment: Villegas Alvarado As I said I know serialize API but I have no Idea how to retrieval serialized data on the form.

Comment: Villegas Alvarado Thank you so much for your attention.
I used your code but I don't know why it doesn't work...
I putted my code here http://jsfiddle.net/BwUM4/1/
I am sure that jQuery plugin works right.
would you please check my code or create sample example on Jsfiddle ?

Comment: Check the javascript code after // End of cookie plugin becasue I am sure that jQuery plugin works right.

Comment: I changed some parts in your jsfiddle and It's running OK now. Some considerations: `.serializeArray()` can be applied only to `<form>` elements, so I replaced your `<div>` by a `<form>`. Also, serialization needs that elements have a name, which I also added to the elements. Now it runs fine!

Comment: @Thank you so much :)
So can't we use serializeArray with Div ?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `.serialize()` and parsing with `.split()` over `.searializeArray()` and JSON parsing.

```
qs = $("#form_id").searialize()  // generates query string, e.g: "name=John&age=21"
f = {}
qs.split("&").map( p => p.split("=") ).forEach( ([k,v]) => f[k] = v )
// f === {name: "John", age: "21"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Edgar's answer but the copy-paste version.

```
var form = $('form');
if (form.length) {
    var form_data = readCookie('saved_form');
    if (form_data != null) {
        string2form(form, form_data);
    }

    form.submit(function() {
        var form_data = form2string(form);
        createCookie('saved_form', form_data, 5);
    });
}

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;

    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ')
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0)
            return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}


function form2string($form) {
  return JSON.stringify($form.serializeArray());
}

function string2form($form, serializedStr) {
  var fields = JSON.parse(serializedStr);
  for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
    var controlName = fields[i].name;
    var controlValue = fields[i].value;
    if (controlValue != '' && $form.find('[name=' + controlName + ']').val() == ''){
        $form.find('[name=' + controlName + ']').val(controlValue);
    }
  }
}
```